# Align image center pysimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I use image (and button) as so:

```
myImg = sg.Image(filename='off.png', key='_CAMIMAGE_')

layout1 = [[myImg],
          [sg.Button('Exit')]]

sg.Window(title="Lights", layout=layout1, size=(500,300), margins=(0, 0)).read()
```

How do I align the myImg to center? I tried google can't find anything
on how to do it. I read somebody suggested justification='center' but I don't know
where to put that. I tried [myImg, justification='center'] didn't work just crash the app.

Comment: did you try `sg.Image(..., justification='center')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on documentation you can use [Column](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#columns-as-a-way-to-modify-elements) with `justification='center'`  to center widgets.

It needs list of rows - like `[[my_img]]`

But it centers `column` in `window`, not `widgets` in `column`
so for row with `Button` it can need separated `Column`.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

my_img = sg.Image(filename='rgb.png', key='_CAMIMAGE_')

# doesn't center Button in Columns
#layout = [
#    [sg.Column([[my_img], [sg.Button('Exit')]], justification='center')],
#]

layout = [
    [sg.Column([[my_img]], justification='center')],
    [sg.Column([[sg.Button('Exit')]], justification='center')],
]

window = sg.Window(title="Lights", layout=layout, size=(500, 500), margins=(0, 0))
window.read()
window.close()
```

[image]

---

`BTW:`

`justification='center'` can be used also in `Text` to center text.

Answer (score 1):

Following code show how it work for option `justification`, `element_justification`, `vertical_alignment`, `expand_x` and `expand_y` of `sg.Column`.

Here, there're two `sg.Column` in horizontal direction and only right one will be adjusted by different options

- For option `justification`, it is for `sg.Column` itself, it won't show any different when there's no extra space for it. Set `expand_x=False`, there will be extra space and option `justification` will work. Actually, it work for this full row, not only on this `sg.Column`. Only last `sg.Column` in this row, set the final attribution `justification`.
- For option `element_justification`, it is for all elements in this `sg.Column`, it will work if you give more space by option `expand_x=True`.
- For option `vertical_alignment`, it will work if there's more space for
  this `sg.Column` in vertical direction "on this row". Set `expand_y=False`, so the height of this `sg.Column` will be lower than the maximum height of this row, then it will work.
- For option `expand_x` and `expand_y`, if True this column will automatically expand in the X/Y direction to fill available space.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def make_window(window=None, justification='left', element_justification='left',
    vertical_alignment='top', expand_x=True, expand_y=True):


    column_layout = [
        [sg.Text("(0, 0)", text_color='black', background_color='yellow'),
         sg.Text("(0, 1)", text_color='black', background_color='green')],
        [sg.Text("(1, 0)", text_color='black', background_color='red'),
         sg.Text("(1, 1)", text_color='black', background_color='blue')],
    ]

    layout = [
        [
         sg.Column([[sg.Text("Fixed Column")]], size=(200, 200), background_color='blue'),
         sg.Column(
            column_layout,
            justification=justification,
            element_justification=element_justification,
            expand_x=expand_x,
            expand_y=expand_y,
            vertical_alignment=vertical_alignment,
            background_color='gray',
            key='Column'),
         ],
    ]

    radios = []
    for group, text in [
            ("justification", ("left", "center", "right")),
            ("element_justification", ("left", "center", "right")),
            ("vertical_alignment", ("top", "center", "bottom")),
            ("expand_x", (True, False)),
            ("expand_y", (True, False))]:
        row = []
        row.append(sg.Text(group, size=(25, 1)))
        for i, value in enumerate(text):
            row.append(sg.Radio(str(value), group, default=eval(f"{group}==value"), size=(6, 1),  enable_events=True, key=(group, value)))
        radios.append(row)

    layout += radios
    win = sg.Window(title="Lights", layout=layout, size=(800, 400), margins=(0, 0), finalize=True)
    if window:
        window.close()
    return win


sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

window = make_window()
justification, element_justification, vertical_alignment, expand_x, expand_y = (
    'left', 'left', 'top', True, True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

    elif isinstance(event, tuple):
        radio = event[0]
        if radio == 'justification':
            justification = event[1]
        elif radio == 'element_justification':
            element_justification = event[1]
        elif radio == 'vertical_alignment':
            vertical_alignment = event[1]
        elif radio == 'expand_x':
            expand_x = event[1]
        elif radio == 'expand_y':
            expand_y = event[1]

        window = make_window(window, justification=justification,
            element_justification=element_justification,
            vertical_alignment=vertical_alignment, expand_x=expand_x,
            expand_y=expand_y)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show code how to use vertical_alignment='center' ?

Comment: Updated as above.